# undefined method `formats' when rendering html.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im using Rails 3.0.3 and  ruby 1.8.7

I want to render /materials/change_prize.html.erb in materials/change_prize.js.erb file.

change_prize.js.erb:

```
$("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:action => 'materials/change_prize.html.erb')) %>");
```

Materials Controller:

```
  def change_prize
    @material = Material.find(params[:id])    

    respond_to do |format|   
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
 resources :materials do
    member do
      get 'change_prize'  
      post 'change_prize'  
    end  
  end
```

but when i load the js file i get this error:

```
undefined method `formats' for nil:NilClass
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use :partial not :action

```
<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "materials/change_prize", :locals => { :xxxx => @xxxx }) %>
```

n.b. xxxx is if you need to pass your object to the partial

Comment: now i get "Missing partial materials/change_prize". Im not trying to render a partial change_prize.html.erb is an action.

Answer (score 2):

Partials have to begin with underscore. So rename your filename to "materials/change_prize.html.erb" to "materials/_change_prize.html.erb". Do note however that when calling it thru the render call you refer to the file WITHOUT the underscore.

```
$("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:action => 'materials/change_prize.html.erb')) %>");
```

Filename : app/views/materials/_change_prize.html.erb